# Sorting a user given array and finding the kth smallest integer within the array

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am doing an assignment for my assembly class, I've got most of it worked out, my only problem is that it doesn't print the right values form the sorted array and k is wrong as well.

Question:
Asking the user to enter an integer, this will be the number of integers they will add into an array, n. Then I created the array and looped through it n times. I then ask for the kth smallest value they want to see from their array. I then sorted the array and printed it and the kth smallest number.

All help is appreciated.

My code:

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data

newline equ 0ah, 0dh
sizeprompt db newline, "Enter the number of elements in the array: ", "$"
requestnumber db newline, "Enter a number into the array: ", "$"
kthsortednoprompt db newline, "Enter the kth smallest number you wish to see: ", "$"
arraysize dw ?
valueofk dw ?
valueofkmessage db newline, "The value of k is: ", "$"
arraysizetest dw 0
arraysizeexceptionmessage db newline, "Array size cannot be less than or equal to zero!", "$"
outofboundsexceptionmessage db newline, "The value entered is out of bounds, please try again!", "$"
array db 50 DUP(?)
bubblesorttemp db ?
printsortedarray db newline, "The sorted array: ", "$"
printthekthsmallestvalue db newline, "The kth smallest value: ", "$"
kthtemp db ?
elemententered db newline, "Value entered: ", "$"

    .code

StartLabel:

extrn readsint : proc, writesint : proc

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

getarraysize:
        lea dx, sizeprompt  
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        call readsint
        cmp ax, arraysizetest
        jle arraysizeexception

        mov arraysize, ax   

        mov si, 0
        mov cx, 0

        jmp elementinsertion

arraysizeexception:
        lea dx, arraysizeexceptionmessage
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        jmp getarraysize

elementinsertion:
        cmp cx, arraysize       
        je kthelementprompt

        lea dx, requestnumber
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        call readsint
        mov array[si], al

        inc si
        inc cx

        jmp elementinsertion

kthelementprompt:
        lea dx, kthsortednoprompt       
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        call readsint
        cmp ax, 0
        jle outofboundsexception
        cmp ax, arraysize
        jg outofboundsexception

        mov valueofk, ax

        mov si, 0
        mov bx, 1

        jmp findkthsmallestvalue

outofboundsexception:
        lea dx, outofboundsexceptionmessage
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        mov valueofk, ax

        jmp kthelementprompt

findkthsmallestvalue:
        mov al, 0
        mov ah, 0
        cmp si, arraysize
        je printarray

        mov ah, array[bx]
        cmp array[si], ah
        jg firstgreaterthansecond

        mov ah, array[bx]
        cmp array[si], ah
        jle firstlessthansecond

        inc si
        inc bx

        jmp findkthsmallestvalue

firstgreaterthansecond:
        mov al, array[si]
        mov bubblesorttemp, al
        mov al, array[bx]
        mov array[si], al
        mov al, bubblesorttemp
        mov array[bx], al

        inc si
        inc bx

        jmp findkthsmallestvalue

firstlessthansecond:
        inc si
        inc bx

        jmp findkthsmallestvalue

printarray:
        lea dx, printsortedarray
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        iteratesortedarray:
                mov ah, array[si]
                call writesint
                inc si
                loop iteratesortedarray

        lea dx, printthekthsmallestvalue
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        sub valueofk, 1
        mov bx, valueofk
        mov ah, array[bx]
        call writesint

end StartLabel
```

Comment: But what *does* it print?  Most people don't want to read through your very long program to figure out what it actually prints, so you should just tell us.  See [mcve].  (Also, you should create a minimal example program that doesn't do what you expect, maybe using static data and some `mov` to put values in registers.  This program is not at all minimal.)

Comment: Also, what do you see when you single-step your code in a debugger?  At which point do the values in registers (or a branch taken/not-taken) stop matching what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

As a first thing I would try to do:

```
    .model tiny
    .code

extrn readsint : proc, writesint : proc

tryToWriteOneInt:
        mov     ah, 255
        call    writesint
        ; exit to DOS with return code 00
        mov     ax,4C00h
        int     21h

end tryToWriteOneInt
```

I guess it will not output 255, nor -1, but something between -1 to -256 (or 65280 to 65535). If it will even output anything, or anything related to `ah` content (impossible to say without seeing the `writesint` code itself, or some documentation of it).

I guess it expects value to print in `ax`, so you will have to learn how to convert 8 bit value to 16 bit value, decide finally on the signed/unsigned type of your array values (as you store only `al` of `readsint`, while the usage of the same procedure to read *size* and *k* suggests it will read 16b signed value, i.e. user entering value -255 will get value 1 stored in the array, or entering value 254 will work during sort as value -2 (how it will get displayed depends how you change your `writesint` usage).

Then you can try to debug your code, instruction by instruction. I can't comment on everything I don't like about it, because I would write here about 15-20 items just about style, and about redundant, ineffective or unreachable code, which doesn't really affect functionality of your code, just makes it harder to read, debug and maintain (or even modify into new app) and causes me pain.

But there are some other problems I will give you hints about.

The bubble sort will do only single pass, so it's not bubble sort. Also it will access one element beyond end of array.

After final output you don't exit back to DOS, so your app will execute any random garbage found in memory after your code. Quite often it will lead to crash of the PC (if you are running just virtual/emulated one, you are much more lucky than students back in PC DOS era, which were just staring at rebooting PC, hoping that the last source is saved to disk correctly, not being lost in some disk cache), or all kinds of funny effects.